# Create Jenkins jobs from a Git directory with job DSL files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a folder in a GitHub project which contains a bunch of groovy files, each containing the DSL for one job e.g: jenkins-as-code/tree/master/jobs contains samplejob1.groovy, samplejob2.groovy, etc.

How would I configure a seed job in Jenkins that would get this list of groovy files from Git and create a job for each one of them.

Comment: This sounds like any other Jenkins job that 1. clones source code into a workspace and 2. runs a series of build scripts. A step to step guide for doing what you're asking would take up a few pages. Have you tried looking at Jenkins documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Solution

In the seed job configuration screen:

1. Clone the git project into workspace in the *Source Code Management* section.
2. Add a *Process Job DSLs* build step, select the *Look on Filesystem* option and enter *jobs/*.groovy* in the DSL Scripts field.

Comment: That just produces and error saying "ERROR: no Job DSL script(s) found at jobs/.groovy*".  Seems to require some XML in that field with an ANT fileset.